# Retrieve models based on created_at timestamp in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$search = $today->subDay(1);
$loading =LoadingBus::where('created_at','=',$search)->get();
dd($loading);
```

gives me  an empty collection. Please what did I do wrong
    Collection {#279 ▼
    #items: []
    }
I have data in my loading_buses table that match this particular date 
for further information

```
dd($search)
Carbon {#278 ▼
+"date": "2016-09-03 00:00:00.000000"
+"timezone_type": 3
+"timezone": "UTC"
}
loading_buses created_at value = 2016-09-03 00:01:06
```

I really need help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass a **Carbon** object but a string that represents the date.

Replace

```
$loading = LoadingBus::where('created_at','=',$search)->get();
```

with

```
$loading = LoadingBus::where('created_at','=',$search->formatLocalized('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Carbon` instance is not equal with record of database in hours,minutes and seconds , you should sing `whereDate` mehtod .
Try this :

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$search = $today->subDay(1);
$loading =LoadingBus::whereDate('created_at','=',$search->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
dd($loading);
```